# javascript - function not calling as and when expected

Tags: javascript

This should be a very basic and easy thing, but I don't really understand this behaviour and I'm searching for a quick explanation on why it's doing what it's doing.

Here's the code I have for now:

```
var addNewResToDb = function () {
    console.log("Add new res to db")
};
var deleteResource = function () {
    console.log("Delete res to db")
};
var editResource = function () {
    console.log("Edit res to db")
};
var searchResource = function () {
    console.log("Search res in db")
};
var getAllResources = function () {
    console.log("Get all res from db")
};

var databaseActions = {
    addNewres: addNewResToDb,
    deleteResource: deleteResource,
    editResource: editResource,
    searchResource: searchResource,
    getAllResources: getAllResources,
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var search = $(".searchbar");
    search.keyup(databaseActions.searchResource);
})
```

So, an object which acts like a "class" and should call a specific variable (function) when required.

After this setup, I'm trying to call `searchResource` on keyup, but it's called on windows load and NOT on every keyup.

My questions here are:

1) Why it's calling on document ready, even if it should be called only on keyup?

2) why it's not calling on keyup?

Sorry for the very basic question, but I'd like to understand this a bit more as I'm trying to use this object approach

Comment: Have you tried changing the syntax to something like `search.keyup = function () {...}` instead of what looks like a function call?

Comment: yes, i also tried something like .on("keyup", searchResource) but not firing

Comment: What about addEventListener method instead of on? `search.addEventListener()`

Comment: Well, on is the jquery way, and jquery is there, I though i could use jquery methods to be honest...i'm going to try to use the event listener as well

Comment: If real desperate you could also try `attachEvent` but that's quite old and probably won't work in a modern browser.

Comment: Code logs as expected http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKqJNj